# What's the best way to detect garbled text in an OCR-ed document

Tags: text, statistics, nlp, ocr

Are there any good NLP or statistical techniques for detecting garbled characters in OCR-ed text? Off the top of my head I was thinking that looking at the distribution of n-grams in text might be a good starting point but I'm pretty new to the whole NLP domain.

Here is what I've looked at so far:

- [N-gram Statistics in English and Chinese: Similarities and Differences](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/33035.pdf)
- [Statistical Distributions of English Text](http://www.data-compression.com/english.html)

The text will mostly be in english but a general solution would be nice. The text is currently indexed in Lucene so any ideas on a term based approach would be useful too.

Any suggestions would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, most powerful thing in that case is Ngrams. You should collect them on related text corpora (with same topic to your OCR texts). This problem is very similar to spellchecking - if small character change lead to great probability increase it was a mistake.  Check [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20221231235757/http://www.alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/querySpellChecker/read-me.html) how to use ngram for spellchecking.

Answer (score 1):

I used n-grams for this some years ago, with pretty decent results. I used Apache Nutch's language detector, that uses word and intraword n-grams internally.Then the "ngram-profile" of your text is compared to n-gram profiles of the training material. Nutch gives a score/confidence value in addition to the language, and I used hard cutoffs based on the language (should be the one the docs are in) and scores. Kept most of the garbeled text out, but it's somewhat computationally costly.